# Getting phone number from Facebook Account Kit

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

The Account Kit documentation states that if your began the login session with AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN, it's possible to access the Account Kit ID, phone number and email of the current account via a call to getCurrentAccount().

Is it possible to get the user's phone number if you began with AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE just like the way Saavn does it?

Comment: i am not entirely sure what you are asking here, your question is quite broad. but there is no way to get the phone number of a facebook user. there is no api for that, it´s just impossible.

Comment: @luschn Facebook introduced the AccountKit which allows a user to log in with just their phone number as seen here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/integrating. When using a token for logging in, it is possible to retrieve the phone number. I need to know if it's possible to do so if I use the CODE method instead.

Comment: ok, didn´t know about that. still, your question is way too broad, you should do some testing and include your code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's possible provided you use LoginType.PHONE in your configuration.

```
    AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final Account account) {
            String accountKitId = account.getId();
            PhoneNumber phoneNumber = account.getPhoneNumber();
            String phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final AccountKitError error) {
            // Handle Error
        }
    });
```

This is your phone number: phoneNumberString; but, `account.getEmail()` will return null if LoginType.PHONE was used in your configuration. 
Vice versa if you use LoginType.EMAIL in your configuration.

Comment: Will or may. Because, for it being available. I think the data would be attached to it unless the user uses phoneNumber to register and not email.

Comment: https://youtu.be/o2-PCiiJzr4 - PHP integration and code samples, just in case to help others.

Comment: @ayz4sci Are you sure that account.getEmail() will return null in that case EVEN IF it is associated with a facebook account?

Comment: Who gets to save the number though? If I get an authorization code, how can I get the phone number on the server side so at to return a signed JWT back to my application?

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of using CODE instead of TOKEN is to shift the token request to your application server. The server uses the Graph api to submit the auth token and if the auth token is valid, the call returns the access token which is then used to verify the user's identity for subsequent API calls.

A graph call to validate the access token returns the account kit id plus additional metadata like the associated phone number and/or email.

```
{  
   "id":"12345",
   "phone":{  
      "number":"+15551234567"
      "country_prefix": "1",
      "national_number": "5551234567"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can fetch Account ID,Email and Phone number using below code:

```
    let accountKit = AKFAccountKit(responseType: AKFResponseType.accessToken)
    accountKit.requestAccount { (account, error) in
     if(error != nil){
        //error while fetching information
      }else{
        print("Account ID  \(account?.accountID)")
        if let email = account?.emailAddress,email.characters.count > 0{
             print("Email\(email)")
        }else if let phoneNum = account?.phoneNumber{
             print("Phone Number\(phoneNum.stringRepresentation())")
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

### If you have `access code/token`...

On `server` or `client`, you can exchange `access token` for `mobile number and country code` with this `FB AccountKit API` - https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.1/me/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx.  Here `xxxxxxxxxx` is your `Access Token`.

### If you have `auth code/token` instead...

You can first exchange the `access code` for an `access token` on the **`server side`** (because it contains the **App Secret**) with this `API` - https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.1/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxxxxx&access_token=AA|yyyyyyyyyy|zzzzzzzzzz.  Here `xxxxxxxxxx`, `yyyyyyyyyy` and `zzzzzzzzzz` are the `auth code`, `app id` and `app secret` respectively.  Once you have the `access token` with it, you can get the `mobile number` with the above mentioned `API`.

Good Luck.